# Keyboard mapping that mostly avoids Shift or Ctrl

Tags: normal-mode

I prefer to avoid pressing Shift and Ctrl keys when navigating code and doing minor edits. I rather type 2 small letters than Shift-key or Ctrl-Key combinations. Yet many commands in Vim require to type Shift or Ctrl, like : or P or Ctrl-f. Is there any useful common remapping for Vim that try to stick to low-case letters and symbols using two-letter combinations if necessary?

Comment: I believe this is not Vim's job to do this kind of things. If you want to change the way you can input a modifier I think this is something you should handle maybe at the OS level or -if this is a possible option or you- directly at the keyboard level with firmware like [QMK](https://qmk.fm/) which allow you to redefine all keys and key combinations how you want. But programmable keyboards are way off topic on this site :)

Comment: @statox I think the point is to create/use a Vim mapping that will use only characters that can be produced without using shift/control. For example, mapping `;` to `:` to start Ex commands, perhaps `\f` to Ctrl-F (assuming backslash is an acceptable key for you), perhaps `\P` for `p`, etc. I don't think there's a standard mapping like this, if you really want one, you might want to write one yourself...

Comment: Ah I might have misunderstood the question indeed. But I agree that doesn't sound like something which already exists.

Comment: @filbranden That was exactly the question. If there is no known mapping, I will create one myself, but I just thought that may be somebody already done this. You know, a mapping for coding/reviewing while holding a cup with favorite beverage...